# Google Classroom How To Post Image

Tags: google-classroom

How can I post an image or simple text on the Google Classroom with python (with or without API)?

I've tried to see reference but didn't find anything with python.

Comment: Add more details in question.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.announcements/create) you can see the documentation. You must inform path parameter courseId and body, something like that:

```
{
  "materials": [
    {
      "youtubeVideo": {
        "id": "w4TJmrOVas4"
      }
    }
  ],
  "text": "Students: see link for my new neurohealth class."
}
```